# Include WooCommerce product to all child categories

Tags: categories, taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I need to include some of my products in all subcategories of category `Auto`. For example - product `Wheel` must be in all subcategories of `Auto`, e.g. `Audi`, `BMW`, `Mercedes`, etc. How to do this without manual choosing of all subcategories?

Comment: When i select( check on checkbox ) parent category i need to check all the subcategories belongs to that parent category. I can’t able to find this option in Woocommerce product filter plugin. I tried the above solution but it doesn't seems to work.. can you please tell me what is 'categorychecklist' ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Paste below code to your functions.php file

```
function my_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

(2) Create **myscript.js** file and paste below code in it and place the file in 'yourtheme/js/' folder.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('#categorychecklist').prepend('<input type="checkbox" id="selectall"><label for="selectall">Select all subcategories.</label><hr>');

    jQuery('#categorychecklist [type="checkbox"]:not(#selectall)').on('change', function () {
        if(jQuery('#selectall').is(':checked')) {
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('ul.children [type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('ul.children [type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
});
```

(3) Done - now selecting your parent category will automatically select child categories if **Select all subcategories** checkbox is selected on product edit page.